# Professional ways of saying "to know something"

Tags: word-choice, expressions, formality, expression-choice

Usually, in our CV or resume, we will say that "I know this, I know that, blah blah". I think the verb "to know" is not formal enough in such situation. Is there a better way to say you know something, like this:

- I know Japanese -> I have knowledge of Japanese

Comment: I don't think it's right to say that "know" isn't formal enough. But in a CV I'm looking for what someone can *do* rather than what they *know*, I wouldn't expect to see the word "know" on a CV at all. In the case of languages you want to say if you can speak/read/write (and to what level). So I wouldn't use either of your sentences. But FWIW "I have knowledge of..." does not sound natural and also sounds like a much lesser claim than "I know..."

Comment: “I know Japanese” is too vague for a CV. Just say how well you know it. Are you conversant at a basic level, do you speak it fluently, can you just about manage to order a sake at an _izakaya_, etc.

Answer (score 3):

"I am proficient in Japanese" is what I would say. You could also say "I am fluent in Japanese".

Comment: Depending on whether those things are true, of course.

Answer (score 1):

I have experience with X for Y years.

My field of expertise include X.

- swap X with Japanese.

** I am fluent in Japanese sounds better then know Japanese. I don't think someone then natives know a language really well. You can use words like I have full bilingual proficiency in Japanese.

Answer (score 0):

Customarily, the CV writer should include whether they write a language or just speak it

An [explanation here](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/10006/how-should-i-indicate-language-proficiency-on-my-resume) -though I find it odd to mention 'read' separately from 'write'

Comment: Why do you find it odd?